# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32' ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, api

I'm trying to learn how to develop an API with ASP.NET. Everything is going well until I try to get connect 2 tables between a foreign key. So I read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#data-annotations) to understand how to work with foreign key.
My user object is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using MyApp.Utils;


namespace MyApp.Models.DataModels
{
    public abstract class UserBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int id_usr { get; set; }

        public string name_usr { get; set; }
        public string surname_usr { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string email_usr { get; set; }
        public int fk_prf_usr { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("fk_prf_usr")]
        public ProfileModel profile { get; set; }
    }

    public class DbUser : UserBase
    {
        private string _password;
        public string password_usr
        {
            get
            {
                return _password;
            }
            set
            {
                _password = value.StrongHash();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this and I try to get users it shows me this page:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32'.
MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetInt32(int ordinal) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\Row.cs, line 177

Stack Query Cookies Headers
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32'.
MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetInt32(int ordinal) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\Row.cs
lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, bool buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator<TSource>.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator, Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs
JoinUpp.API.Controllers.UsersController.GetUsers() in UsersController.cs
+
            return await _context.user_usr.ToListAsync();
lambda_method(Closure , object )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable+Awaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

And I don't know how to fix this issues, I hope that someone can help me to fix this problem.
I think it depends on this rows:

```
public int fk_prf_usr { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("fk_prf_usr")]
public ProfileModel profile { get; set; }
```

because if I comment this rows my API works.

Comment: Do you have some data in the table User and Profile when you run this code? If yes, are you sure that all the correct information to satisfy the relationship is present in your foreign key field?

Comment: Thank you! You solved my issue! I will vote you. I had data and the fk_prf_usr was null so it doesn't satisfy the relationships